# How to control speed of RollingUpdate

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment configured in yml using RollingUpdate:

```
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 10%
```

I'd like to be able to slow down the deployment to give a longer window in which I can pause and possibly rollback.

Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't really have a way of controlling this (the speed of the rolling updates). `maxUnavailable: 0, maxSurge: 10%` seems like a step gap hack.

If you are concerned about your update being ready and having the ability to rollback, you should consider creating a canary [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). In other words, another Deployment with a small number of replicas, that you can delete if something goes wrong.

Another alternative is looking at a Service-Mesh like [Istio](https://istio.io) that allows you to do [Canary Deployments](https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-canary/).

Comment: Oh, `maxUnavailable` and `maxSurge` are just my current RollingDeploy config. Didn't mean to suggest I was using those to control the speed. Figured I'd just paste my current RollingDeploy config incase I'm missing something.

Canary sounds like a good step for now.

Comment: gotcha, wasn't really sure if you meant that. Thx!

Comment: Hm, also wasn't sure if `minReadySeconds` could be used for this purpose. But in any case, might be more of a hack than your canary suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

For those who are already using ArgoCD, its reasonably easy to slow down and control the speed of a deployment using Canary strategy for ArgoCD Rollouts.

https://argo-rollouts.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features/canary/

The `type: Rollout` controller uses the same schema as the `type: Deployment` you get out of the box, however there is a `strategy: canary` that works very similar to `strategy: rollingUpdate` but allows for predetermined pauses in-between each pod coming up.

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 4
  ...
  strategy:
    canary:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
      steps:
      - setWeight: 25
      - pause: { duration: 10m } # wait 10 minutes
      - setWeight: 50
      - pause: { duration: 10m } # wait 10 minutes
      - setWeight: 75
      - pause: { duration: 10m } # wait 10 minutes
      - setWeight: 100
```

With this setup you can control the speed of rolling out each replica as well as abort any deployment gracefully halfway through.